# Maximum likelihood estimator in Uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, function

For Random sample with uniform distribution in
 Tetha< x< Tetha +1 
What's the maximum likelihood function how can we maximize it?

Comment: what have you done to attempt this question?

Comment: Many versions of this question have been answered here: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+maximum+likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood function is:
$$p(x|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i|\theta)= \prod_{i=1}^n I(\theta < x_i<\theta+1)$$
The maximum value of this function is $1$, and the $\theta$ satisfying this maximum value is not unique , i.e. $\theta\in (x_{max}-1,x_{min}+1)$, if the interval is not empty, which can happen when the model is wrong, or there is noise.